# Add 1 in an sql field when a div is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a page where photos are uploaded, when you see the photos there is a button to give you points to the photo.

To the button I gave an onclick with a javascript function that has this php code

```
function puntos(){
        <?php 
        mysql_query("UPDATE 'fotos' SET 'relevancia=relevancia+1' WHERE 'id = $id'");
        ?>
    }
```

This is in photo.view.php in photo.php I have this code that retrieves the id of the selected photo

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : false;
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you cant mix php(mysql) with javascript like that -- look up AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're far from home.

Back to basics first:

**Server vs. client**

mysql and PHP run on the server

JavaScript runs on the client in their browser.

This means javascript cannot access your database directly, you need to do a lot of work before you get there.

Detecting and reacting on a click is something JavaScript can do (and is quite adept at doing).

**Communication**

Normally when a page downloads it and the components it refers are sent from the server to the client over HTTP.

Once in the browser, to get something back from the client to the server the only way is to send another query or open up some network connection somehow from the client to the server which then transfers that content, or indicates somehow what happened on the client.

Traditionally this meant a form and a click resulting in a GET or POST HTTP request and a reload of the page in the browser.

That's till we got:

**AJAX**

Essentially the connection from the client to the server can also be initiated by JavaScript itself and it can talk to a server component (just like the browser can) without having to reload a page or having to submit a form or so). This allows one to create things where a click or even a move of the mouse (or anything else JavaScript can detect -it can detect a lot-) can result into data being sent to the server and answers collected by that JavaScript. If it updates the page (aka DOM) is up to the script to chose.

**Server Side**

Now having JavaScript on the client communicating with the server still isn't going to let said JavaScript update a database. So you need a sever side component that does stringent validations (the code you have above is a horror story from the security side should that ever get to work) and updates a database behind it as needed.

**TL;DR**

Suggest you read up more on how to do simple AJAX

Some starting points:

- https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp
- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/AJAX_Security_Cheat_Sheet

But there's much more out there for sure.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación y el tiempo. Sabia que algo me faltaba y no podia encontrar que. Todavia queda mucho por aprender. Gracias!